# What are analogs of FreeBSD functions cgetfirst(), cgetnext(), cgetstr() in modern Linux environment?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, std, freebsd

I am trying to port old C code from FreeBSD into Ubuntu. The code contains calls to some functions specific for old FreeBSD C-standard library (`stdlib.h`). What are the analogs of these functions in modern Linux library?

```
char *cgetcap (char *, char *, int);
int cgetclose (void);
int cgetent (char **, char **, char *);
int cgetfirst (char **, char **);
int cgetmatch (char *, char *);
int cgetnext (char **, char **);
int cgetnum (char *, char *, long *);
int cgetset (char *);
int cgetstr (char *, char *, char **);
int cgetustr (char *, char *, char **);
int strcasecmp (const char *, const char *);
```

Comment: `strcasecmp()` is a POSIX function (declaration in `<strings.h>` — yes, plural).  The others I don't know about.

Comment: Those functions are for accessing a BSD capability database. Have you tried the `libbsd` compatibility package on Ubuntu?

Comment: @jxh I have checked libbsd releases at https://libbsd.freedesktop.org/releases/
those functions are not ported/implemented there yet :-((((.